# React Native cannot build

Tags: android, node.js, facebook, react-native

I am following the guide located at: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

However, calling `npm install`, the error appears:

```
> bufferutil@1.2.1 install C:\Users\KJA\ReactNativeProjects\AwesomeProject\node_
modules\bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\KJA\ReactNativeProjects\AwesomeProject\node_modules\bufferutil>if not d
efined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\n
ode-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node
"" rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYT
HON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\nod
e_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:401:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node
-gyp\lib\configure.js:356:11
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodej
s\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\KJA\ReactNativeProjects\AwesomeProject\node_modules\buffer
util
gyp ERR! node -v v5.7.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.2.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN install:bufferutil@1.2.1 bufferutil@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN install:bufferutil@1.2.1 Exit status 1

> utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install C:\Users\KJA\ReactNativeProjects\AwesomeProject\n
ode_modules\utf-8-validate
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\KJA\ReactNativeProjects\AwesomeProject\node_modules\utf-8-validate>if n
ot defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\b
in\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (n
ode "" rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYT
HON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\nod
e_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:401:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node
-gyp\lib\configure.js:356:11
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodej
s\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\KJA\ReactNativeProjects\AwesomeProject\node_modules\utf-8-
validate
gyp ERR! node -v v5.7.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.2.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN install:utf-8-validate@1.2.1 utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp re
build`
npm WARN install:utf-8-validate@1.2.1 Exit status 1
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fseve
nts@1.0.11
```

How can this be alleviated?

**update**

I downloaded node-gyp, and the 2.7.x version of python, but now when running `npm install`, the errors appear:

```
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_proces
s.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodej
s\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\KJA\ReactNativeProjects\AwesomeProject\node_modules\utf-8-
validate
gyp ERR! node -v v5.7.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.2.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN install:utf-8-validate@1.2.1 utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp re
build`
npm WARN install:utf-8-validate@1.2.1 Exit status 1
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fseve
nts@1.0.11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on Windows and I see a node-gyp error.

This is actually well [documented](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/629#issuecomment-151018292) already. I'd suggest reading that issue thread for more details.

Just based off that error message though, it says it can't find Python. Do you have python installed and properly put in your path?

That issue thread mentions installing Visual C++ Build Tools to fix the node-gyp issues. So try that and see if it works.

Comment: I have had non-stop problems doing anything in this environment. I downloaded node-gyp, and the 2.7.x version of python, but now when running npm install, the errors appear:

Comment: I got this to work!!, at least get passed the point I was. I did not run react-native start

Comment: Awesome glad to hear. Did you try installing Visual C++ build tools btw? thats supposed to help alleviate the node-gyp errors.

Comment: I have a more pressing issue. For some reason my project is attempting to locate the dependencies inside of another file, not the one where the support libraries are. How can I change this?

Comment: got any stack trace? what folder? tough to offer a potential solution with specifics unfortunately.

Comment: I figured it out again basically I have two locations on my desktop where there are Android source files it was referencing the one that was very old and outdated